# Remote `docker-compose build`: workaround slow connections

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, automated-deploy

I'm using docker-compose to deploy into a remote host. This is what my config looks like:

```
# stacks/web.yml
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.3
    restart: always

  web_server:
    depends_on: [postgres]
    build: ../sources/myapp
    links: [postgres]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nginx_socks:/tmp/socks
      - static_assets:/source/public

  sidekiq:
    depends_on: [postgres, redis]
    build: ../sources/myapp
    links: [postgres, redis]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_assets:/source/public

  nginx:
    depends_on: [web_server]
    build: ../sources/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - nginx_socks:/tmp/socks
      - static_assets:/public
    restart: always

volumes:
  db:
  nginx_socks:
  static_assets:

# stacks/web.production.yml
version: '2'

services:
  web_server:
    command: bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///tmp/socks/puma.production.sock
    env_file: ../env/production.env

  sidekiq:
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -e production -c 2 -q default -q carrierwave
    env_file: ../env/production.env

  nginx:
    build:
      args:
        ENV_NAME: production
        DOMAIN: production.yavende.com
```

I deploy using:

```
eval $(docker-machine env myapp-production)`
docker-compose -f stacks/web.yml -f stacks/web.production.yml -p myapp_production build -no-deps web_server sidekiq
docker-compose -f stacks/web.yml -f stacks/web.production.yml -p myapp_production up -d
```

Although this works perfectly locally, and I did couple successful deploys in the past with this method, now it hangs when building the "web_server" service and finally show some timeout error, like I describe in [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3975).

I think that the problem originates from the combination of my slow connection (Argentina -> DigitalOcean servers on USA) and me trying to build images and push them instead of using hub hosted images.

I've been able to do deploy by cloning my compose config into the server and running `docker-compose` directly there.

The question is: **is there a better way to automate this process? Is a good practice to use docker-compose to build images on the fly?**

I've been thinking about automating this process of cloning sources into the server and `docker-compose`ing stuff, but there may be better tooling to solve this matter.

Comment: Use docker-hub -- building the images you need every time you need them is bad-practice and effectively untestable. Create one artifact and promote it between environments, from CI, through test, and into prod.

Comment: What about the parameterization? I don't think I want to build and push mulitple images of say, nginx, one per environment.

Comment: Accept parameters from environment variables

Comment: As @dnephin said, the parameters should be used by the container, at runtime, not the image at build time. You can arrange things so that there is a bootstrap script to configure the container for a specific environment and store the config files on the host or in a data volume if you don't want to do it every time you start up a new container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was remote building images. This implies pushing the whole source needed to build the image over the net. For some images that was over 400MB of data sent from Argentina to some virtual servers in USA, and proved to be terribly slow.

The solution is to totally change the approach to dockerizing my stack:

- Instead of building images on the fly using Dockerfile `ARG`s, I've modified my source apps and it's docker images to accept options via environment variables on runtime.
- Used DockerHub automated build, integrated with GitHub.

This means I only push changes -no the whole source- via git. Then DockerHub builds the image.

Then I `docker-compose pull` and `docker-compose up -d` my site.

Free alternatives are running your own self-hosted docker registry and/or possibly GitLab, since it recently released it's own docker image registry: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/.